# How to send MMS using Native SDK + BB10

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I have gone through the "Sending SMS sample" application and it's working fine. I have modified the code (only attachment) to send an MMS. I have a picture Lion.jpg in assets folder of the project. Picture size is less than 41KB.

Below is the modified code:

```
QUrl url("asset:///Lion.jpg");
messageBuilder->addAttachment(bb:im::message::Attachment("image/jpeg", "body.txt", url));
```

The rest of the code is same as in sending SMS. Code is compiled properly and run properly. But MMS wasn't received to another phone.

I have checked INBOX on my device, in which my code is running. It shows the message with no picture and a red clock-like icon. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately programmatically sending an MMS is not possible at this time.